# Entity Framework Core: calling `Load()` after `Include()`

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When requiring to eager load certain relations, I have noticed that in EF Core (v. 1.1.0) calling the `Include` method alone will not attach the required relation to the query, and when dealing with situation such as when the query must be passed to a view (ASP.Net MVC Core) where lazy loading will not work this causes problems.

However, I know that calling the `Load` method after the `Include` solves this problem. On the other hand, I also know that the `Load` is very similar to `ToList` as all the data available in a table will be loaded into the memory.

The point is that, I have faced situations where I have to call `Load` in order to be able to make a query based on properties available in a relation and I believe that this is a bad idea and using a `Join` would be more appropriate.

There are two questions:

1- Is calling `Load` really a bad idea in comparison with using a `Join` in order to attach navigational or relational properties?

2- What is the point of `Include` then if it does not include things on its own?

Comment: You really have to show code examples to make your point.

Comment: If `.Include()` is not including your navigation properties, there is probably something wrong with your mappings. Please post your mappings & queries.

Comment: `Load` is not similar to `ToList`. Load fetches only related data not the whole table.